# How to model these relations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I currently have the following model structure and relations

```
class Fleet < ApplicationRecord
  # properties id, created_at, updated_at

  # A fleet should only consists of the same type, either a fleet or cars or a fleet of trains. Never both
    has_many :cars
    has_many :trains 
end

class Car < ApplicationRecord
  # properties id, created_at, updated_at, number_of_gears, is_sports_car 

  belongs_to :fleet
end

class Train < ApplicationRecord
  # properties id, created_at, updated_at, number_of_wagons, people_capacity, has_first_calass_section

  belongs_to :fleet
end
```

The problem i have is thata fleet should only consists of the same type, either a fleet of cars or a fleet of trains. Never both.

With the current relations on fleet, it seems error prone to have both has_many associations (or more coming like Airplanes) in terms of integrity and ease of use when calling `@fleet._cars-or-trains`, i would have to know what i can call.

STI is not an option since the properties are very different on a Car and a Train. There are many more properties, for the sake of simplicity i have shortened them in this example.

What is the right way in Rails to do this?

Comment: What do the two types of Fleets have in common?

Comment: Not much, just 2-3 fields of about 10-13 total fields

Comment: If they have so little in common, do they need to be in the same model?

Comment: No, that's why i have a separate Car and Train model

Comment: Oh. `CarFleet` and `TrainFleet` then.

Answer (score 1):

I would use two different models: CarsFleet and TrainsFleet. Both can extend a Fleet model but define a different `has_many` association.

Then "Car" would belong to a cars_fleet and "Train" would belong to a trains_fleet.

Answer (score 1):

This is what [polymorphic relationships](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) are for.

A `Fleet` could have many `vehicles`, and a `Vehicle` could be either a `Car` or a `Train` and, importantly, never both.

```
class Fleet < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :vehicles, polymorphic: true # notice the belongs_to, it's the only way polymorphism works from memory
end

class Car < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :fleet, as: :vehicle
end

class Train < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :fleet, as: :vehicle
end
```

That way you can call `fleet.vehicles` and not worry about the class.

This code is untested but it should get you across the line, and it's the most Railsy-way to solve your issue.

Comment: A fleet can have many cars or many trains. I don't see how that would work with this example

Answer (score 0):

You could add a model validation to check this:

```
class Fleet < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :cars
  has_many :trains

  validates :cars, absence: true, if: -> { trains.any? }
  validates :trains, absence: true, if: -> { cars.any? }
end
```

The above should stop fleets from being saved when they have both cars and trains present. However you can still create cars and trains separately and link them to a fleet.

```
# assuming a valid fleet exist
fleet = Fleet.create # should save

# you can still create both cars and trains
fleet.cars.create # should save
fleet.trains.create # should save

# however when you retry to save the fleet it fails on the validation
fleet.save # should fail
```

In the above scenario we would like to also fire the fleet validations when creating a car or train. To do this add a [`validates_associated`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validates-associated):

```
validates_associated :fleet
```

In both the `Car` and `Train` model. This now should withhold the above car and train to be saved.

---

Note that this answer doesn't prevent anything SQL related and records are still technically allowed in the database. If you don't want this you have to build a trigger that runs `AFTER INSERT` and `AFTER UPDATE`. Since this is SQL related I would suggest asking a new question if you have any issues with trigger creation. Mention the database used since the trigger syntax is not the same for all database types (MySQL, SQL Server, ...).